# Fancybox настройки ширины модального окна

Tags: fancybox

Здравствуйте! передо мной стоит задача: при открытии картинки в окне фансибокса, чтобы ширина была фиксированной. пробовала различные варианты , не помагает

вот код

```
 $(".imageFancy").fancybox({
        'width':300, 
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'autoSize':false

     });
```

еще пробовала добавлять к настройкам `type: iframe` и максимальную ширину, но ширина не устанавливается, лишь подстраивается под текущий размер окна

версия  `jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js`
можно ли вообще в fancybox сделать подобное?
спасибо!

Comment: А какой type у Вас? inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите параметры:

```
maxWidth
maxHeight
```

Если не сработает, то обновите библиотеку. Последняя версия уже 2.1.5: http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/